# Uploading folder from local directory to VM instance jupyterlab folder too slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to upload a zip folder (20GB) from my laptop to my VM instance

```
gcloud compute scp /Users/yudhiesh/Desktop/frames_split.zip jupyter@tensorflow-5-vm:data
```

It works but is painfully slow even with my regular upload speeds being about 2-3 MB/s so what can I do to speed it up?

```
frames_split.zip                                       0%  195MB 249.4KB/s 24:14:18 ET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by sending keep alive packets to server from the SSH client on every 60 seconds

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Add the following:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I would recommend you to try this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#gcstransfer) to transfer file to instance

- [Create a new Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) or identify an existing bucket that you want to use to transfer files
- From your laptop, upload files to the bucket with below command

`gsutil cp OBJECT_LOCATION gs://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/`

- SSH in to your VM `tensorflow-5-vm` (assuming this is Linux VM)
- copy the file to your instance with below command

`gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME SAVE_TO_LOCATION`

NOTE: make sure your VM does has [scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) enable to Cloud Storage bucket and your VM service account has permission to access the bucket